# Is there a cleaner way to return an object from an arrow function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to return an object from an arrow function, like this function `f`:

```js
myMethod(f: data => { 
  return { someField: data.something };
});
```

I know that for simple types you can shrink the arrow function to just be `data => data.something`.

Is this possible when you are returning an object i.e. something like this:

```js
myMethod(f: data => { someField: data.something });
```

That doesn't compile, I assume because the compiler thinks the `{` is the start of a function, not the start of an object.

Is there a syntax here which works, or should I just carry on using the longer form with the `return` in?

Comment: Are you using `data => { someField: data.something }` as a type? If not, I'm not sure this syntax `myMethod(f: data => { someField: data.something });` is correct

Comment: That syntax 100% _isn't correct_! I'd like it to be, but it won't compile. My data type is `{ someField: number }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the object with parenthesis:

```
myMethod((f: data) => ({ someField: data.something }));
```